# Why do Oracle's sequences skip their cached values when attempting to re-create the sequence?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sequence

Consider the following code:

```
create sequence "s" cache 50;
select "s".nextval from dual;
```

When I execute the above once, I get

```
NEXTVAL
-------
1
```

When I execute the statements twice, apart from the obvious error message on the DDL statement, I am getting

```
drop sequence "s";
create sequence "s" cache 50;
select "s".nextval from dual;
create sequence "s" cache 50;
select "s".nextval from dual;

NEXTVAL
-------
51
```

Run the statements three times to get:

```
drop sequence "s";
create sequence "s" cache 50;
select "s".nextval from dual;
create sequence "s" cache 50;
select "s".nextval from dual;
create sequence "s" cache 50;
select "s".nextval from dual;

NEXTVAL
-------
101
```

The [doc reads](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_6017.htm#SQLRF01314):

> If a system failure occurs, then all cached sequence values that have not been used in committed DML statements are lost.

But does a failing DDL statement qualify as a system failure? What's the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Could you please provide script example? I tried to reproduce with steps: create sequence, call `nextval`, DDL statement with no error, DDL statement with error. I got consequent values of sequence (1, 2, 3, 4, ...) without no gaps.

Comment: Cannot repeat this in Oracle 11.2.0.2.0. I get `1` then `2` then `3` then `4` when I connect in SQL Developer and SQLPlus simultaneously - even if I connect as different users.

Comment: I was able to replicate it. What I did was created the sequence as OP has demonstrated. Fetched values. Then again executed the same DDL. This time on accessing the Sequence, the values start from 51 (assuming you cached 50 values). It skips all cached numbers every time you executed the same DDL (creating the same sequence)

Comment: This is what I noticed - When we execute DDL for the first time, an entry is made in v$DB_OBJECT_CACHE. Until the time you fetch the sequence value, you will notice that there is no entry for `shareable_mem' column which stores the `amount of shareable memory in shared pool consumed by object`. As soon as you fetch the nextval (for the first time), you will notice that there is a value for this `shareable_mem' column. When we execute the DDL again, this entry is flushed and `shareable_mem` is reset to 0 - of course letting go of the cached values. That explains what is happening.

Comment: Adding to my above comment, I noticed this behavior as consistent with other DDLs too. I created a table and noticed an entry in `V$_DB_OBJECT_CACHE` with a value for `shareable_mem'. As soon as I executed the same DDL `shareable_mem` value is reset to 0! This means that on DDL errors, this value is always reset.

Comment: @Incognito: Nice observation. I suspect that it is not relevant that the DDL produces errors. This value would be reset also for `ALTER` statements, true?

Comment: That's right! I just did a quick demo. The shareable_mem always resets to 0 on any operation on the same object!

Comment: If you issue DDL on other objects even on the sequence itself (except the CREATE) the current cache is intact.

Comment: @Incognito . . . You should write up your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When we execute **DDL** (`CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ1 CACHE 50`) for the first time, an entry is made in `v$DB_OBJECT_CACHE`.

Until the time you fetch the sequence value, you will notice that there is no entry for `shareable_mem` column which stores the amount of shareable memory in shared pool consumed by object. As soon as you fetch the next value of the sequence (for the first time), you will notice that there is a value for this `shareable_mem` column (Oracle allocates memory in shared pool).

When we re-execute the DDL (same statement), `shareable_mem` is reset to 0 - of course letting go of the cached values. At the same time, remember that Oracle has stored the `LAST_NUMBER` for this sequence (as 50 when we created the sequence for the first time). Since the `shareable_mem` is flushed and the cached values are gone, `LAST_NUMBER` is now updated to `CURRVAL + *CACHE SIZE*`

This behavior (of resetting the `shareable_mem`) is consistent with other DDLs too. I created a table and noticed an entry in V$_DB_OBJECT_CACHE with a value for `shareable_mem`. As soon as I executed the same DDL `shareable_mem` value is reset to 0!